# Could Not Fetch while I am using Youtube Channel Url to import YouTube channel title and subscibers using Importxml

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract data from youtube. Using channel url and importxml function for channel title and nubmer of subscribers of a channel. I try with different xpath but always shoting Could Not Fetch url. Is it possible to extract .

Answer (score 0):

1. Check a URL.
2. Check if the XPath is valid.
3. Suggestions:

- **title** -> xml2::importXML(url, "//[@id="channel-header"]/h1/span[1]")
- **subscribers** -> xml2::importXML(url, "//[@id="subscriber-count"]/ytd-subscriber-count-renderer/span")

Comment: =importXML("https://www.youtube.com/@GiaplusMedical","//[@id="subscriber-count"]/ytd-subscriber-count-renderer/span")

Not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).